# Font size in \pmatrix: Elegant Summation in big Vectors

Tags: amsmath, matrices, vector

Is there a way to make this look more elegant?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sum_{j=1}^{q_{k}} \frac{\vec{e}_{k,j}}{b_{k,j} -  \vec{m}_{k,j}^T \vec{x}_{k} - \vec{e}_{k,j}^T \vec{u}_{k}} \\
        \sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+1}} \frac{\begin{pmatrix} \vec{e}_{k+1,j} & \vec{m}_{k+1,j} \end{pmatrix}^T}{b_{k+1,j} -  \vec{e}_{k+1,j}^T \vec{u}_{k+1} -  \vec{m}_{k+1,j}^T \vec{x}_{k+1}} \\
        \vdots \\
        \sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+N-1}} \frac{\begin{pmatrix} \vec{e}_{k+N-1,j} & \vec{m}_{k+N-1,j} \end{pmatrix}^T}{b_{k+N-1,j} -  \vec{e}_{k+N-1,j}^T \vec{u}_{k+N-1} -  \vec{m}_{k+N-1,j}^T \vec{x}_{k+N-1}} \\
        \sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+N}} \frac{\vec{m}_{k+N,j}}{b_{k+N,j} -  \vec{m}_{k+N,j}^T \vec{x}_{k+N}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which compiles to

[image]

As you can see, the **numerators are of different font sizes**, also **alignment within the vector** might help, as well as **modifying the separating space between entries**. Maybe none of this helps, and I have to live with some not-so-pretty-vector. Any advice? Thanks!

*Note: in the real document, I am not using `\vec{}`, but `\boldsymbol{}` to distinguish vectors from scalars, without effect on this problem.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose another layout, with medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` and an alignment of the sum symbols, thanks to the `pmatrix*` environment from `mathtools` and package `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{eqparbox, booktabs}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\scriptstyle#2$}}
\newcommand{\msum}{\medop\sum\limits}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix*}[l]
 \msum_{j=1}^{\eqmathbox{q_{k}}} \mkern-12mu \frac{\bm{e}_{k,j}}{b_{k,j} - \bm{m}_{k,j}^T \bm{x}_{k} - \bm{e}_{k,j}^T \bm{u}_{k}} \\ \addlinespace
\msum_{j=1}^{\eqmathbox{q_{k+1}}} \mkern-12mu \frac{\bigl(\bm{e}_{k+1,j} \enspace \bm{m}_{k+1,j}\bigr)^T}{b_{k+1,j} - \bm{e}_{k+1,j}^T \bm{u}_{k+1} - \bm{m}_{k+1,j}^T \bm{x}_{k+1}} \\
\eqmathbox{ ⋮ } \\[0.5ex]
        \msum_{j=1}^{\eqmathbox{q_{k+N-1}}}\mkern-12mu \mfrac{\bigr( \bm{e}_{k+N-1,j} \quad \bm{m}_{k+N-1,j} \bigr)^T}{b_{k+N-1,j} - \bm{e}_{k+N-1,j}^T
 \bm{u}_{k+N-1} - \bm{m}_{k+N-1,j}^T \bm{x}_{k+N-1}} \\ \addlinespace
 \msum_{j=1}^{\eqmathbox{q_{k+N}}}\mkern-12mu \frac{\bm{m}_{k+N,j}}{b_{k+N,j} - \bm{m}_{k+N,j}^T \bm{x}_{k+N}}
\end{pmatrix*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The fractions are still not aligned.

Comment: @egreg: I added a negative kerning in the third row and indeed forgot to add it in the other rows. Thanks for pointing it

Comment: +1, although I'm not a fan of “mid size”.

Comment: I think it is useful to avoid too great discrepancies in size,  e.g.  textstyle vs displaystyle fractions, or for polynomials with fractional coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

Use always `\dfrac` and `\limits`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sum\limits_{j=1}^{q_{k}} \dfrac{\vec{e}_{k,j}}{b_{k,j} -  \vec{m}_{k,j}^T \vec{x}_{k} - 
        \vec{e}_{k,j}^T 
        \vec{u}_{k}} \\
        \sum\limits_{j=1}^{q_{k+1}} \dfrac{\begin{pmatrix} \vec{e}_{k+1,j} & \vec{m}_{k+1,j} 
        \end{pmatrix}^T}{b_{k+1,j} -  \vec{e}_{k+1,j}^T \vec{u}_{k+1} -  \vec{m}_{k+1,j}^T \vec{x}_{k+1}} \\
        \vdots \\
        \sum\limits_{j=1}^{q_{k+N-1}} \dfrac{\begin{pmatrix} \vec{e}_{k+N-1,j} & \vec{m}_{k+N-1,j} 
        \end{pmatrix}^T}{b_{k+N-1,j} -  \vec{e}_{k+N-1,j}^T \vec{u}_{k+N-1} -  \vec{m}_{k+N-1,j}^T 
        \vec{x}_{k+N-1}} \\
        \sum\limits_{j=1}^{q_{k+N}} \dfrac{\vec{m}_{k+N,j}}{b_{k+N,j} -  \vec{m}_{k+N,j}^T \vec{x}_{k+N}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would try ``\\[1ex]`` (or similar) in order to space out a bit the rows; also `\vec{e}^{\,T}` would avoid the “T” clashing with the arrow. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen that the main problem is that you are using `pmatrix` environment inside another `pmatrix` environment. That's causing the differences in sizes between the numerator and denominator.

One solution, if you don't fully understand the code that you have with the `pmatrix`, is to use plain arrays. You can create an array of one column, and every entry in that array is one summation. If you want more space, add a blank line or create a new line.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[  % begin math environment
\left(  % left parenthesis
\begin{array}{c}  % begins an array of one column

\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k}} \frac{\vec{e}_{k,j}}{b_{k,j}-\vec{m}_{k,j}^\vec{x}_{k}-\vec{e}_{k,j}^T \vec{u}_{k}} \\ % some space
\\ % more space
\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+1}} \frac{\left(\vec{e}_{k+1,j}~\vec{m}_{k+1,j}\right)^T}{b_{k+1,j}-\vec{e}_{k+1,j}^T \vec{u}_{k+1}-\vec{m}_{k+1,j}^T\vec{x}_{k+1}} \\ % some space
\\ % more space       
\vdots \\ % some space
\\ % more space
\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+N-1}}\frac{\left(\vec{e}_{k+N-1,j}~\vec{m}_{k+N-1,j}\right)^T}{b_{k+N-1,j}-\vec{e}_{k+N-1,j}^T\vec{u}_{k+N-1}-\vec{m}_{k+N-1,j}^T \vec{x}_{k+N-1}} \\ % some space
\\ % more space 
\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+N}}\frac{\vec{m}_{k+N,j}}{b_{k+N,j}-\vec{m}_{k+N,j}^T\vec{x}_{k+N}}

\end{array}  % ends array
\right)  % right hand side parenthesis
\] % ends math environment

\end{document}
```

Another solution would be to not use `pmatrix` environments in the summations. Just use `\left( \right)` for the *big* parenthesis, like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[  % begin math environment
\begin{pmatrix}

\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k}} \frac{\vec{e}_{k,j}}{b_{k,j}-\vec{m}_{k,j}^\vec{x}_{k}-\vec{e}_{k,j}^T \vec{u}_{k}} \\ % some space
\\ % more space
\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+1}} \frac{\left(\vec{e}_{k+1,j}~\vec{m}_{k+1,j}\right)^T}{b_{k+1,j}-\vec{e}_{k+1,j}^T \vec{u}_{k+1}-\vec{m}_{k+1,j}^T\vec{x}_{k+1}} \\ % some space
\\ % more space       
\vdots \\ % some space
\\ % more space
\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+N-1}}\frac{\left(\vec{e}_{k+N-1,j}~\vec{m}_{k+N-1,j}\right)^T}{b_{k+N-1,j}-\vec{e}_{k+N-1,j}^T\vec{u}_{k+N-1}-\vec{m}_{k+N-1,j}^T~\vec{x}_{k+N-1}} \\ % some space
\\ % more space 
\sum_{j=1}^{q_{k+N}}\frac{\vec{m}_{k+N,j}}{b_{k+N,j}-\vec{m}_{k+N,j}^T\vec{x}_{k+N}}

\end{pmatrix}
\] % ends math environment

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @plr .

`\left(\vec{e}_{k+N-1,j}~\vec{m}_{k+N-1,j}  \right)^T` looks good to me, and adding `\\ %more space` ;)

The only change is that in the numerator, on needs to add `~` to force a separation between `\vec{e}` and `\vec{m}` to not lose the information of concatination in the `\left( ...\right)`-brackets.

I will accept @user187802 's answer though, as it is more sophisticated.